# Flex Spark Datagrid Cell 1 * Cell 2 stored in Cell 3

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex-spark

I am kinda new with datagrids and spark, and been wracking my brain to figure this out. I have a datagrid being loaded with an XMLList. One field is a numeric value that will be calculated times another field and that result be stored and displayed in the grid on the fly.

Example:

XML

```
<SampleTable>
 <Row>
  <Item>Item 1</Item>
  <Quantity>10</Quantity>
  <Price></Price>
  <Cost></Cost>
 </Row>
</SampleTable>
```

So a user would enter in the price, and the Cost would be updated in the grid with the Price * Quantity values, with the dataprovider being updated with the result when the form is saved.

Adding in the grid and the XML is already bound. I can get simple updates to the cells to work. I need help figuring out where to do a calculation. Only the price is editable, and when that cell changes value I want the Cost to be calculated.

Handlers for the editing session:

```
        import spark.components.gridClasses.CellPosition;
        import spark.events.GridEvent;
        private var mouseDownRowIndex:int;
        private var mouseDownColumnIndex:int;
        protected function dataGrid_gridMouseDownHandler(event:GridEvent):void
        {
            mouseDownRowIndex = event.rowIndex;
            mouseDownColumnIndex = event.columnIndex;
        }

        protected function dataGrid_gridMouseUpHandler(event:GridEvent):void
        {
            // Start a grid item editor if:
            // - the rowIndex is valid
            // - mouseUp is on the same cell and mouseDown
            // - shift and ctrl keys are not down
            // - cell is editable
            // - an editor is not already running
            // An editor may already be running if the cell was already
            // selected and the data grid started the editor.
            if (event.rowIndex >= 0 &&
                event.rowIndex == mouseDownRowIndex && 
                event.columnIndex == mouseDownColumnIndex &&
                !(event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey) &&
                event.column.editable &&
                !event.grid.dataGrid.itemEditorInstance)
            {
                event.grid.dataGrid.startItemEditorSession(event.rowIndex, event.columnIndex);
            }
        }

<s:DataGrid id="dgTest" x="10" y="68" width="900" editable="true" electionMode="singleCell" requestedRowCount="4"                   gridMouseDown="dataGrid_gridMouseDownHandler(event)" gridMouseUp="dataGrid_gridMouseUpHandler(event)">
<s:columns>
<s:ArrayList>
<s:GridColumn width="250" dataField="Item" headerText="Item" resizable="true" sortable="false" editable="false"></s:GridColumn>
<s:GridColumn width="160" dataField="Quantity" headerText="Quantity" resizable="false" sortable="false" editable="false"></s:GridColumn>
<s:GridColumn width="90" dataField="Price" headerText="Price" resizable="false" sortable="false" ></s:GridColumn>
<s:GridColumn width="90" dataField="Cost" headerText="Cost" resizable="false" sortable="false" editable="false"></s:GridColumn>
</s:ArrayList>
</s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your datasource Bindable.

So in code (AS), this would be:

```
[Bindable]
var myXMLList:XMLList;
```

I don't think it is possible to bind to an XMLList however. You should make use of an XMLListCollection instead.

It's still not clear to me if your want to save your data somewhere, or if you just want to visualize...

s:GridColumn has a property called "labelFunction". Maybe this is sufficient for your needs.

```
public function myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
{
    var amount:Number = item.Quantiy;
    var price:Number = item.Price;
    return amount*price as String
}
```

In you example

```
<s:GridColumn width="90" dataField="Cost" headerText="Cost" resizable="false"  sortable="false" editable="false"></s:GridColumn>
```

would be changed into

```
<s:GridColumn width="90" dataField="Cost" headerText="Cost" resizable="false"  sortable="false" editable="false" labelFunction="myLabelFunction"></s:GridColumn>
```

Provided code is by no means complete. It serves as an example.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using an itemrenderer. It's ugly but works.

What I am having trouble with is moving this event to when the PercentComplete field is changed instead of the click event on this field. This is the timing I am having trouble with.

```
                <s:GridColumn width="90" dataField="Extension" headerText="Extension" resizable="false" sortable="false" rendererIsEditable="true">
                    <s:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:GridItemRenderer mouseDown="itemrenderer1_dataChangeHandler(event)">
                                <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                                        import spark.events.GridEvent;

                                        protected function itemrenderer1_dataChangeHandler(event):void
                                        {

                                            if(data){
                                                var data_field:String = ((parseFloat(data['PercentComplete'])/100)*parseFloat(data['Weight'])).toFixed(2).toString();
                                                this.dataLabel.text = data_field;
                                                data.Extension[0] = data_field;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]]>
                                </fx:Script>
                                <s:Label id="dataLabel" text="{data.Extension}" height="100%" width="100%" textAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle"/>

                            </s:GridItemRenderer>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </s:itemRenderer>
                </s:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Datagrid is owner of the datasource, not the GridItemRenderer.
Therefore you should not use mouseDownEvents. (What will happen when to Tab trough your cells?). You might even consider moving this kind of business logic away from your view into your controller (or your model).

For your example, your really don't need a "fancy" GridItemRenderer. Everything has to be calculated outside of your datagrid.

The spark Datagrid has an event which is call "gridItemEditorSessionSave".

> **spark.components.DataGrid.gridItemEditorSessionSave**
>
> Dispatched after the data in item editor has been saved into the data
>   provider and the editor has been closed.
>
> **Event Type:** spark.events.GridItemEditorEvent.GRID_ITEM_EDITOR_SESSION_SAVE
>
> **Language Version:** 3.0
>
> **Player Version:** Flash 10, AIR 2.5
>
> **Product Version:** Flex 4.5

Personally I would implement a Bindable ValueObject and convert my XMLList in an IList implementation, for example and ArrayCollection, containing a set of those objects. Example follows:

```
[Bindable]
public class MyValueObject
{
   public var percentComplete:Number;
   public var weight:Number;

   public function get extension():Number
   {
      return percentComplete*weight;
   }
}
```

If you populate your datagrid with these ValueObjects, you can use a dumb view and even better, you can use any view you like without having to change your actual application. (Isn't that the purpose of OO Programming?)

This question is completely different than the first one though. I'm willing to provide answers, but you should do some research on your own.

Comment: I looked into the gridItemEditorSessionSave event, but I needed these fields calculated and displayed in the grid on the fly, not at the end. Functionality I am trying to reproduce is like a spreadsheet.

Comment: My example will give you the functionality of a spreadsheet. A spreadsheet will only recalculate formulas after you're done editing a cell. If you really want to recalculate _during_ the editing of your PercentComplete ItemRenderer, you could try make use of an KeyDown Eventlistener (which registers keystrokes), but I personally would advise against it.